# Meteor publish subscribe with aggregate data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a two different collection collection A and collection B.
collection B has primary key of the collection A.

If there are 10 records in collection B with the primary key of collection A then i want new field countsInB and it will be 10

i have created publish method of the collection A and also get that count in collection A method.

so it works perfect. i have taken reference from https://forums.meteor.com/t/why-is-mongo-aggregation-not-reactive-in-meteor/7462/6

```
Collection A :
[{"_id":"123456"},{"_id":765456}]
Collection B:
[{"_id":"dfsdfsdf",aid:"123456"},{"_id":"fsfds",aid:"123456"}]

collectionA = new Mongo.Collection('A');
```

code inside the publish method:

```
Meteor.publish("publishMethodOfA",function(){
  var sub = this;
  sub.ready();
  var query = collectionA.find();
  var handle = query.observeChanges({
    added: function (id) {
      //added function
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      //remove method
    },
    changed: function (id) {
      //change method
    },
    error: function(err){
      throw new Meteor.Error('Uh oh! something went wrong!', err.message);
    }
  });

  var pipeline = [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "B",
        localField: "aid",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "counts"
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id" : 1,
        "counts" : { $size: "$counts" }
      }
    }
  ]
  collectionA.aggregate(pipeline);

  sub.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

when there is change in collection A that method works completely fine and   it invokes as well so there is no any issue

but when there is any insertion in collection B so in that case i want to update the count in publish method of A. so how can i do that?

Comment: support your question with Code written. You are asking us to imagine things. it is difficult :)

Comment: @AnkurSoni i have added code and every thing is inside publish method as there is insertion in collection B then how i can get that updated count in A?

Comment: I have exactly this pattern but for performance I actually update the count in the parent document when children are added/removed using [matb33:collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks)

Comment: @MichelFloyd  right i have also followed the same method